# 95% confidence intervals and the null hypothesis

Tags: confidence-interval, t-test

I have performed an unpaired t-test comparing the means of two groups. My hypothesis was that the stroke group mean would be significantly higher than the control group mean. However, the t-test revealed no significant difference. Here are the results:

```
control mean   stroke mean   p value    95% confidence interval
   0.0864        0.0927       0.76         -0.0388 to 0.0263
```

I understand that the range of the CI is high, suggesting that the study was underpowered. However, do the CI infer anything else about the possible true effect? So, the CI is located more within the negative zone than the positive zone. Does this mean that it is more likely that the control mean could be higher than the stroke mean?

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding something, but is not the stroke mean 0.0063 higher (0.0927 - 0.0864)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most useful aspect of a statistical test is that it warns us against overinterpreting our results. Humans are very good at "seeing" paterns in random noise. Think for example of a [Rorschach test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rorschach_test). A statistical test is there to warn us when that happens. It does so by giving us a non-significant result. So I am afraid your result is just that your study is underpowered.

Comment: It is unusual to have an asymmetric CI from a t-test, have you double-checked the options used to run it and made sure they match your design? If you haven't already, you should also evaluate your data for adhering to the assumptions of the test. In general, the true difference of means is expected to be __anywhere__ within the CI, it is no more likely to be near the center than near the ends. There are many posts here about Null Hypothesis Significant Testing (NHST), worth checking out given your question.

Comment: @svannoy I don't think it is unusual at all to have an asymmetric CI from a t test. The CI of the difference will be centered on the actual difference between means. It will only be symmetrical when the actual mean difference is zero.

Comment: @HarveyMotulsky I based my comment on the common procedure of computing CIs, namely your test statistic +/- critical value * standard error. I know this formula does not hold for some test statistics, such as Cohen's d, but _assumed_ (I know, my bad), it does hold for the difference of means when you are comparing two independent samples with equal variance. I did a quick search to try and find info to the contrary but didn't see anything. If you have a reference handy, that would be great.

Comment: @svannoy The test statistic for a two-sample t-test is simply $\bar{x}_1 - \bar{x}_2$. (The different varieties of the test are to do with how to calculate the std error.) So the confidence interval will usually be offset from 0.

Comment: My apology for muddying the water @Kim. I see the CI you provided is symmetrical around your difference of means (math error on my part checking the data). I stand by the notion that the CI should be symmetrical, but around the test statistic not zero.

Comment: PS - I'm not sure you should conclude that the study is underpowered. You could do a power test to determine the necessary sample size to reject the null hypothesis that the difference of means is zero when the observed difference is 0.0063. But, any observed difference could be deemed statistically significant if the sample size is large enough. More important is to consider what would be a clinically (practically) significant difference (i.e. a difference that makes a difference) and then determine the sample size necessary to reject the null if you observe a difference of that magnitude.

Comment: Hi @svannoy Thanks for your input. To calculate the sample size necessary to reject the null hypothesis do I just use the known SD from the current study? I know there is some nice sofware out there that performs the sample calculation

Comment: Also, if the sample size required to detect a clinically significant difference is huge (>100, which is highly impractical for in vivo work), can I say put in a statement along the lines of "even if the sample size was increased it is unlikely that an effect size would be detected"?

Comment: @Kim one of the assumptions of the t-test is equal variance so yes, you can use the sample SD from your study; and yes, there are a number of power calculators you can use. Generally, a _clinically significant_ difference is fairly large and thus reduces the sample size needed to reject the null. However, there are many cases in the medical literature of small effect sizes found to be statistically and clinically significant at the population level (see aspirin and heart attacks). These are decisions and nuances requiring content/method expertise, hopefully you can get some local consultation.